# Lazarus SQL showing specific datas

Tags: jquery, sql, database, lazarus

I have a question again.

I wont to filter a specific row from a sql database and want to show them in a listbox.

When i use this code, i get the whole row displayed in the Listbox.

[code=pascal]procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
     SQLQuery1.Close;
     SQLQuery1.SQL.text:='SELECT * FROM Auftrag ';

```
   while (SQLQuery1.Eof = false) do
      begin
     Listbox1.Items.add(SQLQuery1.Fields[1].AsString);
      SQLQuery1.Next;

      end;
```

end; [/code]

But when i apply my filter function, I just get the first record from the table.
But I want all records with the same date.

[code=pascal]procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
     SQLQuery1.Close;
     SQLQuery1.SQL.text:='SELECT * FROM Auftrag where Fertig = :Fertig';

```
 SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Fertig').AsString := Edit1.Text;
 SQLQuery1.Open;

   while (SQLQuery1.Eof = false) do
      begin
     Listbox1.Items.add(SQLQuery1.Fields[1].AsString);
      SQLQuery1.Next;

      end;
```

end;[/code]

Its basically a shedule sofware.

My table looks like :

Person               Date
Person1             10.24.2016
Person2             11.28.2016
Person3             11.28.2016
Person4             12.29.2016
...

Date format is the same in the sql and the edit form.

Comment: Your text is difficult to read and to understand. You have a table containing the fields "Person" and "Date" - right? But your second SQL filters for a field "Fertig" - what's that? There is no field "Fertig" in your table. Or do you mean the field "Date"? Then the "where" part of the SQL should be "where Date = :Fertig"

Comment: Something messed up,  my table has Person and fertig , and fertig contains the dates

Comment: You are indexing on [1] in the example, so you are returning that value repeatedly. The index needs to be variable. The code is confused, you use a while loop and then index on a value.  FWIW, "fertig" means "finished".

Comment: The [1] is a field index, (columns) not rows/tuples